# compute determinant of a matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, matrix

I'm trying to compute determinant of a matrix in JS. I used algorithm from http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-compute-determinant-matrix/ but I lost my mind on the last condition. I just do not understand. Can you help me?

This is how looks like my code right now. In another function I create an empty 2d array and then copy it to det function. Next I retrieve values from html and then trying to compute determinant of a matrix. The first 2 cases are simple but I have a problem with the last one. I couldn't find working example in JS.

```js
function det() {
  var det = 0;
  var array1 = array.slice();

  for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

    for (j = 0; j < array1[i].length; j++) {
      array1[i][j] = parseInt(document.getElementById("element" + (i + 1) + (j + 1)).value, 10);
    }

  }

  if (array1.length == 1) {
    det = array1[0][0];
  } else if (array1.length == 2) {
    det = (array1[0][0] * array1[1][1]) - (array1[1][0] * array1[0][1]);
  } else {

  }

}
```

Comment: in the last condition , you create a sub matrix which is `array1` deleting the row and column at `a0j` where `j` is from `0` to `N`, you multiply `a0j` with `det(subarray)` and the sum of the products is the final `determinant` , that is the definition of `determinant`, the code written before the recursive call is just filling the subarray that's all

Comment: Recursion is nice, but be warned with js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224520/are-functions-in-javascript-tail-call-optimized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see definition of the determinant for square matrix here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n_.C3.97_n_matrices.
Algorithm used in http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-compute-determinant-matrix/ use some properties of determinat to calculate it in recursive way as sum over all permutations. In this way you get `N * N!` operations! It is very big even for small `N`.

For solving this problem you can first transform matrix to triangular with the same determinant and after that calculate determinant as product of all diagonal elements.

Answer (score 11):

I may suggest my solution, based on recursive algorithm, which takes only few lines of code and, I guess, will suit most of practical applications:

```js
const determinant = m => 
  m.length == 1 ?
  m[0][0] :
  m.length == 2 ? 
  m[0][0]*m[1][1]-m[0][1]*m[1][0] :
  m[0].reduce((r,e,i) => 
    r+(-1)**(i+2)*e*determinant(m.slice(1).map(c => 
      c.filter((_,j) => i != j))),0)

const test1 = [[3]]                      // 3
const test2 = [[3,-2],[7,4]]             // 26
const test3 = [[1,3,7],[2,-1,4],[5,0,2]] // 81

console.log(determinant(test1))
console.log(determinant(test2))
console.log(determinant(test3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I created a Matrix class with some function for the basic operations, one of them the determinant calculation**

Here we have the constructor

```
constructor(rows,cols) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.vals = new Array(rows*cols);
    for(let i = 0; i < this.vals.length; i++) this.vals[i] = 0;
}
```

and here the determinant function

```
determinant() {
    if (this.rows != this.cols ) {
        console.log("Matrix must be square");
        return;
    }
    let size = this.rows;
    if (size == 1) return this.vals[0];
    if (size == 2) return this.vals[0]*this.vals[3]-this.vals[1]*this.vals[2];
    let sign = 1;
    let result = 0;
    for (let k = 0 ; k < size ; k++){
        let cofactors = new Matrix(size-1,size-1);
        cofactors.vals = this.vals.slice(size,size*size).filter((_,index)=>index%size!=k);
        result += sign * this.vals[k] * cofactors.determinant();
        sign*=(-1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).