# Very big recursion javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I have this code, which is counting array elements sum with recursion, but when the array is too big it throwing **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error.

```
var a = new Array(10 ** 7);
a.fill(0);

function sum(arr, i = 0) {
  if(i === arr.length) {
      return 0;
  }

  return arr[i] + sum(arr, i + 1);
}

sum(a);
```

So I need to change it somehow to work normally for all cases and I thought I can make it work asynchronously with Promises, but it always returning **Promise pending**.

```
var a = new Array(10 ** 7);
a.fill(0);

var sum = (arr, i = 0) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(i === arr.length) {
      return resolve(0);
    }

    return  sum(arr, i + 1).then(el => el + arr[i]);
  }, 0);
});

sum(a);
```

How can I fix it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why do you need recursion at all, can't you just reduce() it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers

Comment: It doesn’t hurt to learn the roots

Comment: Of course, I can, but it's a task and I have to modify the code and make it work for big arrays

Comment: If you *must* use recursion, you're going to have to do a divide-and-conquer instead of tail recursion.  There's no way you're going to manage 10^7 entries on the stack and [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224520/are-functions-in-javascript-tail-call-optimized) only Safari does tail call optimization.

Comment: Don't use recursion for for this task (in javascript). You are overcomplicating this: `const sum = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`

Comment: Does `return resolve(sum(arr, i + 1).then(el => el + arr[i]));` do what you need?

Comment: @JustinHeath no. It again returns Promise pending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some solutions for your issue with using native tasks. this one is using Promise to schedule a microtask:

```
(function() {
  function sum(arr, i = 0) {
    if(arr.length === i) {
        return Promise.resolve(0);
    }

    return Promise.resolve(null)
      .then(() => sum(arr, i + 1))
      .then((x) => x + arr[i]);
  }

  sum(a).then(s => console.log(s));
}());
```

but this will force the engine to wait until the execution is completed. So for huge arrays, I wouldn't recommend you doing this on the main thread.

You can also do the following:

```
(function() {
  function sum(arr, i = 0) {
    if(arr.length === i) {
        return Promise.resolve(0);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        sum(arr, i + 1).then(x => resolve(x + arr[i]));
      });
    });
  }

  sum(a).then(s => console.log(s));
}());
```

then with make a few changes to this code and making it more elegant, we can do the following:

```
(function() {
  const defer = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve));

  async function sum(arr, i = 0) {
    if(arr.length === i) {
        return 0
    }

    await defer();
    return await sum(arr, i + 1) + arr[i];
  }

  sum(a).then(s => console.log(s));
}());
```

and if your environment supports tail recursion you can change this to use it: http://2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html

## UPDATE

actually, there is one more way to do this. rxjs library provides a queue scheduler which can help you make a recursive logic to be iterative without making many changes in your code. I've created an example of your `sum` method [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-queue-scheduler-for-recursion).

Answer (score 2):

You are only resolving the case where i is arr.length, so all the chained promises remain pending forever. Return won´t automatically resolve it for us, so need to be explicit:

```js
var a = new Array(10);
a.fill(0);
a[0] = 3;
var sum = (arr, i = 0) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(i === arr.length) {
      resolve(0);
    } else {
      resolve(sum(arr, i + 1).then(el => el + arr[i]));
    }
  }, 0);
});

sum(a).then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you would want to use promises and make the function async. But if you do you need to resolve both cases:

```
const sum = (arr, i = 0) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(i === arr.length) {
      return resolve(0);
    }

    return  sum(arr, i + 1).then(el => resolve(el + arr[i]));
  }, 0);
});
```

Now this also returns a promise. Once you've gone async you can never go back. You need to use the returned promise to get the return value:

```
sum([1, 2, 3, 4]).then(return => console.log(return));
```

Its better to not make it async. ES6 supports tail recursion so you can just make it like this:

```
function sum(arr) {
    function helper(acc, i) {
        if (i<0) {
            return acc;
        }
        return helper(arr[i]+acc, i-1);
    }

    return helper(0, arr.length - 1);
}
```

Since the order doesn't matter I took the liberty to sum the values in reverse.  Now believe it or not, but that `helper` already exists in the language as an abstraction that gives you the value of each element and the `acc` in each iteration. Thus you can do this instead:

```
function sum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
}
```

Comment: *"ES6 supports tail recursion"* not on any implementation I'm aware of. Babel pulled the feature over a year ago too.

Comment: Also, why `setTimeout` in the Promise constructor?

Comment: @user633183 It's OPs code. I just added the missing `resolve`. Since it is a requirement it will work on all ES6 compliant implementations. Safari/iOS supports tail recursion and is perhaps the most ES6 compliant. Now you are aware of one.

Comment: whoa, newfound respect for Safari ✊

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` is not a solution for the stack overflow problem. Managing your stack is a matter of sequencing your function calls. You can do this in a variety of ways, the most intuitive being the `loop`/`recur` trampoline.

```js
const loop = f =>
{ let acc = f ()
  while (acc && acc.tag === recur)
    acc = f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ tag: recur, values })

const sum = (xs = []) =>
  loop ((result = 0, i = 0) =>         // initial state
    i >= xs.length                     // exit condition
      ? result                         // return value
      : recur (result + xs[i], i + 1)) // next state
      
const tenMillionNumbers =
  Array.from (Array (1e7), (_,n) => n)
  
console.time ('recursion is not slow')
console.log (sum (tenMillionNumbers))
console.timeEnd ('recursion is not slow')

// => 49999995000000
// recursion is not slow: 2171ms
```

I cover many other techniques for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596323/633183).

Stack-safe recursion is something I write about a lot, with [almost 30 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20stack-safe) on the topic

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new Array(1000);
a.fill(1);
function sum(arr, i = 0, res = 0, resolve) {
  if(!i) return new Promise((resolve) => sum(arr, i + 1, res + arr[i], resolve), 0); 
  if(i === arr.length) return resolve(res);
  setTimeout(function(){
    sum(arr, i + 1, res + arr[i], resolve);
  }, 0); 
}
sum(a).then(console.log);
```

Comment: Need some explanation of code what you wrote and how it will solve problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an iterative process instead of recursive one. So instead of accumulating calls, you'd compute your sum on each iteration call. This can be achieved by using a helper function which will get `(sum, array, currentValue)`

Comment: Even inside your function?

Comment: @AngelaHayrapetian Sure don't use prebuilts but you must be able to make your own helpers

Comment: @AliaksandrSushkevich Yes. I have to make it work asynchronously, that's why I've tried to do that with promises, but I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score -1):

If for whatever reason you *need* to use recursion and don't mind this taking a *long*, you could use a timeout; however I would absolutely *not* recommend using this. I'm mostly posting it because it's possible.

```
var arr = new Array(10 ** 7);
    arr.fill(0);

var len = arr.length,
    idx = 0,
    sum = 0,
    sumFn = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        sum += arr[idx];
        idx++;

        if (idx < len) {
            sumFn();
        } else {
            //complete
        }
      }, 1);
    }

sumFn();
```