# Repeated xml request with setTimeout, tail call optimized? (In js)

Tags: javascript, recursion, xmlhttprequest, tail-recursion

I am trying to understand recursion and tail call optimization.
I have this example code below and it seems not to be TCO. Why is it not and how can I change it to be optimized?

```
const getState = () => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com', true);
  xhr.onload = () => console.log(xhr.response);
  xhr.send();
};

(function updateState() {
  getState();
  setTimeout(updateState, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: had you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224520/are-functions-in-javascript-tail-call-optimized

Comment: @Edwin on a second look it seems related and the material provided is interesting & useful for my understanding. Still, I am looking for an up to date implementation example here on SO.