# does the callback function of an async function push to call stack in a conditional recursive sync function?

Tags: javascript

```js
let canExit = false;

setTimeout(function() {
  canExit = true;
}, 1000);

function recc() {
  if (canExit) {
    console.log("Bye bye…");
  } else {
    console.log("always else…");
    recc();
  }
}

recc();
```

I think I get it, let me know if my understanding is wrong!

Comment: Your current code results in a `SyntaxError`, you might want to correct that. There also aren't any `async` functions in there? That term has a very specific meaning

Comment: yeah i corrected it, hope setTimout is async!!

Comment: @SrikanthGowda Functions inside `setTimeout` and `setInterval` calls will only run as soon as all synchronous calls have been completed. Which is why `setInterval(,0)` is used to run a function asynchronously.

Comment: @nickzoum i know that, thats what i am trying to say, a callback function of an async function will not pushed to call stack.

Answer (score 1):

No, but there is a chance if recc() function is asynchronous. so never ever depend on a value in recursive function being changed from a async function.

Answer (score 0):

Initiating a call to the synchronous function `recc` with a timer makes no difference to whether `recc` creates a new, additional, stack frame each time it calls itself recursively.

Synchronous recursion will generally add a new frame to the stack on each recursive call unless both

1. the recursive call is written to meet the criteria of [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33923/5217142), in that is directly returns the value returned by calling itself, without subjecting the value to additional operations, and
2. the JavaScript engine being used [implements the capability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37224520/5217142) to recognize and optimize tail recursion by not generating a new stack frame.