# Is async code in a Promise always an antipattern?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, anti-patterns, non-recursive

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050114/1874170) that it can be an antipattern to *mix* `Promise`s with `async` code.

Does this, however, apply *in all cases*?

I can't see an easy way to avoid combining them in the following code:

- It's an alternative to `setInterval` which waits for an invocation to *complete* before scheduling the next one
- However, unlike [recursive `setTimeout`](https://medium.com/@devinmpierce/recursive-settimeout-8eb953b02b98), it does not constitute an open memory leak in browsers that [don't yet support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37224563/1874170) TCO

Does this code embody an antipattern? And, if so, how can I remedy it without introducing a memory leak?

See, in particular, line 10: `new Promise( async (resolve) => {`

—this seems very non-idiomatic, but I don't see another way to accomplish: wrapping an `await` statement in a `while` loop *per se*, dispatching it, and returning a handle to abort the loop.

```js
var [setRepeatedTimeout, clearRepeatedTimeout] = (() => {
    const asleep = (delay) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
    const repeatedTimeoutIntervals = [];

    function setRepeatedTimeout(f, delay, ...arguments) {
        //Like setInterval, but waits for an invocation to complete before scheduling the next one
        //(Supports both classic and async functions)
        const mySemaphores = {notAborted: true};
        const intervalID = repeatedTimeoutIntervals.push(mySemaphores) - 1;
        new Promise( async (resolve) => {
            await asleep(delay);
            while(mySemaphores.notAborted) {
                await f(...arguments);
                await asleep(delay);
            }
            delete repeatedTimeoutIntervals[intervalID];
        });
        return intervalID;
    }

    function clearRepeatedTimeout(intervalID) {
        //Clears loops set by setInterval()
        repeatedTimeoutIntervals[intervalID].notAborted = false;
    }

    return [setRepeatedTimeout, clearRepeatedTimeout];
})();
```

```html
<p><button onclick="(function createInterval(){
  const _ = {intervalID: undefined};
  _.intervalID = setRepeatedTimeout( () => {
    console.log(`Hello from intervalID ${_.intervalID}`)
  }, 2000)
})()">Create timer</button><br />
<form action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="(function clearInterval(intervalID){
  clearRepeatedTimeout(intervalID);
})(parseInt(event.target.elements.intervalID.value))">
<input name="intervalID" placeholder="intervalID"/><button type="submit">Clear timer</button></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that the other question was warning about, and that could be a problem here, is that if the inside of the async callback passed to the Promise constructor awaits something that rejects, the Promise will *hang* instead of rejecting. Your current code will not result in `f` ever rejecting, but `setRepeatedTimeout` were to carry out a task which may reject, you'd get an unhandled rejection and permanent hanging:

```js
var [setRepeatedTimeout, clearRepeatedTimeout] = (() => {
    const asleep = (delay) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
    const repeatedTimeoutIntervals = [];

    function setRepeatedTimeout(f, delay, ...arguments) {
        //Like setInterval, but waits for an invocation to complete before scheduling the next one
        //(Supports both classic and async functions)
        const mySemaphores = {notAborted: true};
        const intervalID = repeatedTimeoutIntervals.push(mySemaphores) - 1;
        new Promise( async (resolve) => {
            await asleep(delay);
            while(mySemaphores.notAborted) {
                await f(...arguments);
                await asleep(delay);
            }
            delete repeatedTimeoutIntervals[intervalID];
        });
        return intervalID;
    }

    function clearRepeatedTimeout(intervalID) {
        //Clears loops set by setInterval()
        repeatedTimeoutIntervals[intervalID].notAborted = false;
    }

    return [setRepeatedTimeout, clearRepeatedTimeout];
})();


const _ = { intervalID: undefined };
_.intervalID = setRepeatedTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Throwing...');
  return Promise.reject();
}, 2000)
```

If you want the loop to continue when such an error is encountered, there's a way to handle such problems while keeping the `async`: just catch everything that might reject (either in a `try`/`catch` or with `.catch`):

```js
var [setRepeatedTimeout, clearRepeatedTimeout] = (() => {
    const asleep = (delay) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
    const repeatedTimeoutIntervals = [];

    function setRepeatedTimeout(f, delay, ...arguments) {
        //Like setInterval, but waits for an invocation to complete before scheduling the next one
        //(Supports both classic and async functions)
        const mySemaphores = {notAborted: true};
        const intervalID = repeatedTimeoutIntervals.push(mySemaphores) - 1;
        new Promise( async (resolve) => {
            await asleep(delay);
            while(mySemaphores.notAborted) {
                await f(...arguments).catch(() => {}); // log error here if you want
                await asleep(delay);
            }
            delete repeatedTimeoutIntervals[intervalID];
        });
        return intervalID;
    }

    function clearRepeatedTimeout(intervalID) {
        //Clears loops set by setInterval()
        repeatedTimeoutIntervals[intervalID].notAborted = false;
    }

    return [setRepeatedTimeout, clearRepeatedTimeout];
})();


const _ = { intervalID: undefined };
_.intervalID = setRepeatedTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Throwing...');
  return Promise.reject();
}, 2000)
```

But there's really no need for the `new Promise` here at all - it never resolves, and never gets used. Just use an async IIFE:

```js
var [setRepeatedTimeout, clearRepeatedTimeout] = (() => {
    const asleep = (delay) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
    const repeatedTimeoutIntervals = [];

    function setRepeatedTimeout(f, delay, ...arguments) {
        //Like setInterval, but waits for an invocation to complete before scheduling the next one
        //(Supports both classic and async functions)
        const mySemaphores = {notAborted: true};
        const intervalID = repeatedTimeoutIntervals.push(mySemaphores) - 1;
        (async () => {
            await asleep(delay);
            while(mySemaphores.notAborted) {
                await f(...arguments).catch(() => {}); // log error here if you want
                await asleep(delay);
            }
            delete repeatedTimeoutIntervals[intervalID];
        })();
        return intervalID;
    }

    function clearRepeatedTimeout(intervalID) {
        //Clears loops set by setInterval()
        repeatedTimeoutIntervals[intervalID].notAborted = false;
    }

    return [setRepeatedTimeout, clearRepeatedTimeout];
})();


const _ = { intervalID: undefined };
_.intervalID = setRepeatedTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Throwing...');
  return Promise.reject();
}, 2000)
```

```
    (async () => {
        await asleep(delay);
        while(mySemaphores.notAborted) {
            await f(...arguments).catch(() => {}); // log error here if you want
            await asleep(delay);
        }
        delete repeatedTimeoutIntervals[intervalID];
    })();
```

Comment: Wow, putting this last paragraph last made me wonder the whole reading "But what do they see this Promise constructor does, I can't see myself?"