# How to avoid Maximum call stack size exceeded when returning a recurring call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack-overflow, tail-call-optimization

I have this small script:

```
const returnCount = (n: number): number => {
  if (n === 0) return 0;
  return returnCount(n - 1);
};

const result = returnCount(100000);
```

which crashes with

```
Project/src/2023/23/test.ts:2
  if (n === 0) return 0;
  ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at returnCount (Project/src/2023/23/test.ts:2:3)
    at returnCount (Project/src/2023/23/test.ts:3:10)
    at returnCount (Project/src/2023/23/test.ts:3:10)
    at returnCount (Project/src/2023/23/test.ts:3:10)
    at returnCount (Project/src/2023/23/test.ts:3:10)
    at returnCount (Project/src/2023/23/test.ts:3:10)
    at returnCount (Project/src/2023/23/test.ts:3:10)
    at returnCount (Project/src/2023/23/test.ts:3:10)
    at returnCount (Project/src/2023/23/test.ts:3:10)
    at returnCount (Project/src/2023/23/test.ts:3:10)
```

And I'm not sure why.

I would understand it if my method what something like

```
const returnCount = (n: number): number => {
  if (n === 0) return 0;
  return 0 + returnCount(n - 1);
};
```

Because it needs to wait for the result of `returnCount(n - 1)` before returning `0 + returnCount(n - 1)`.

But in the case of `return returnCount(n - 1);`, I thought the stack trace would be *"shortcuted"* since the result of `returnCount(n)` would be the result of `returnCount(n - 1)`.

How to make it behave like that so I don't hit the `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error?

Comment: "*I thought the stack trace would be "shortcuted"*" - no engine has implemented proper tail calls yet

Comment: "*How to make it behave like that so I don't get a stack overflow?*" - use a `for` or `while` loop

Comment: If you want to keep things still feel recursive, you could also try using the trampoline technique,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224520/are-functions-in-javascript-tail-call-optimized  In my testing it's also faster than pure recursion too (your example for me was 10ms), for smaller number like 10400, recursion 4.2ms, tramp: 3.4ms, (that was unexpected).  Of course the while loop @Bergi mentions I would expect to be even faster.

Comment: Change to a loop - remove the recursion.

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript When the code runs, all the things happen inside the call stack and firstly the global execution context is created.
In the case of your recursion case, it is throwing so many functional execution context inside the call stack. So you can use a loop here instead of recursion for the bigger values.

```
   let result = 0;
  
   while (n !== 0) {
    n -= 1;
    result += 1;
   }
  
   return result;
   };

   const result = returnCount(100000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's try to understand the following from your code and question.

**Why does it crash?**

Every browser (javascript runtime ) has a certain limit on call stack size.
For example, in Firefox, it is 26441 (depending on your version). When this limit exceeds it throws an exception.

**How to fix it?**

A quick workaround would be to know the browser stack size and then you can conditionally prevent it like this.

```
GetStackSize=()=>{
   let count = 0;
    const fn=()=>{
         count++;
         fn();
        }
      try {
          fn();
      }catch(e) {

      }
    return count;
 }
let maxStack=GetStackSize();

const returnCount = (n: number): number => {

    //to avoid max limit exception
    if (n === 0 || n>maxStack) return 0;

     return returnCount(n - 1);
 };

 const result = returnCount(100000);
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: 26441 what? stack frames? bytes?

Comment: @Bergi Every browser (javascript runtime ) has a certain limit on call stack size. For example, in Firefox, it is 26441 (depending on your version).

Comment: You already wrote that. But in which unit did you measure this size?

Comment: 26441 is the number of times the function can make a call to itself, however, note that this number can vary based on the memory  required by each recursive call

Comment: Yes, so this number is quite useless

Comment: "*Counting the call stack limit*" does not work, as "*the number varies based on the memory required by each recursive call*". So even if the limit for `GetStackSize` is `26441`, the limit for `returnCount` may be something entirely different.

Comment: And then, doing `if (n>maxStack) return` is just ridiculous. Avoiding an error by just not running the code is not a solution. In a real function, this would simply compute wrong results!

Comment: I still suggest you to read the question carefully