# Can functional programming be learned with Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Scala is a multi-paradigm language, and functional is one of those paradigms.  I'd like to learn functional programming, and Scala has many other characteristics that attract me (it's a rising star, runs on JVM, has access to Java libraries, etc.)  My question is: Is the functional part of Scala sufficient to learn the **basics** of functional programming?

Comment: To apply functional techniques, at the very least you need *function arguments* and *closures*. Many languages, including JavaScript, Perl, Go, Lua, C++11, Scheme provide nice implementations for this (some like Python, Php and Ruby are less nice). Further functional “extras” are tail recursion, immutability, “everything is an expression” and advanced type systems incl. type inference. Ocaml, Haskell and Scala have these, but Scala is first and foremost an object-oriented language, which can occlude some functional aspects. So Scala is sufficient, but requires OO unlike Scheme, Haskell, Ocaml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Coursework](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun) and a [book](http://pragprog.com/book/mbfpp/functional-programming-patterns-in-scala-and-clojure) and another [book](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) say yes.  If you want far more than the basics, you can add in a [library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) full of mind-bending corners which has a handy [tutorial](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Scala has all the features that make a language functional. Though no standard definition, functions as first-class, being able to pass functions as parameters, immutability, tail recursion and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166155/is-scala-a-functional-programming-language?rq=1).

Scala is however object-functional, where one can use objects and/or functions to solve a problem based on the problem space. If you wish for such flexibility, it  would be best to take a look.

PS:\ In Scala 2.11 we expect macros in scala.